# Disable Persistent Database Connections on HHVM running as FastCGI

Tags: php, mysql, mysqli, hhvm

I'm running HHVM version 3.0 as FastCGI whith NGINX.
I would like to know where disable php MySQL persistent connections.

In traditional php is on the php.ini file as follows:

```
[MySQL]
mysql.allow_persistent = Off
```

It's not clear in the HHVM documentation how to do this.

When a I try the code below:

```
<?php
echo "Display erros: " . ini_get('display_errors') . "<BR>"; // Only for test
ini_set('mysql.allow_persistent', '0');
echo "Mysql persistent: " . ini_get('mysql.allow_persistent') . "<BR>";
?>
```

I get the output below:

```
Display erros: 1
Mysql persistent:
```

How to disable persistent connections in HHVM?

Comment: As an aside, HHVM 3.0 was released almost a year ago, and has been unsupported since last spring (when 3.1 came out). You should upgrade to either the current 3.5 stable release, or to the 3.3 LTS series.

Answer (score 0):

`mysql.allow_persistent` is changeable as [`PHP_INI_SYSTEM`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysql.configuration.php), which means [only in `php.ini` or your server config](http://php.net/manual/en/configuration.changes.modes.php). As a result, you can't use `ini_set` to change it.

`var_dump(ini_set('mysql.allow_persistent', '0'));` will indicate to you that your call is returning `FALSE`, indicating a failure to change the value.

HHVM uses `php.ini` just like other methods of running PHP. Depending on your install, it may use one in a different location. Check `phpinfo()`'s output for the location - it may be in `/etc/hhvm` somewhere.

Comment: In HHVM things are different... The output of phpinfo() is only: HipHop

Comment: @TomirSchmiteJr. Sorry, you're right. Check http://php.net/manual/en/function.php-ini-loaded-file.php?